# SQL Server configuration in Lumen

Tags: sql-server, api, rest, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to set Lumen with SQL Server, but I can not ...
My .env file is:

```
DB_CONNECTION = sqlsrv
DB_HOST = MYSERVER
DB_DATABASE = MIDB
DB_USERNAME = MIUSER
DB_PASSWORD = MIPASSWORD
```

Lumen does not throw any errors, but is left wondering, do nothing.
we could explain the correct way to set up for another engine database than not MySQL.
Greetings, thank you very much.

Comment: Note: In order for your configuration values to be loaded, you will need to uncomment the Dotenv::load() method call in your bootstrap/app.php file.  http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/database#configuration , I dont know if that's the problem, just making sure you did all the steps here

Comment: Rinor Dreshaj, Thanks for responding. I had forgotten to clarify earlier, it was already uncommented as they say on the official website of Lumen.

I'm investigating it can be.

Greetings and thank you very much for responding.

Comment: @Daniel did you ever get an answer to this?